# How to optimize SpaCy pipe for NER only (using an existing model, no training)

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am looking to use SpaCy v3 to extract named entities from a large list of sentences. What I have works, but it seems slower than it should be, and before investing in more machines, I'd like to know if I am doing more work than I need to in the pipe.

I've used ntlk to parse everything into sentences as an iterator, then process these using "pipe" to get the named entities. All of this appears to work well, and python appears to be hitting every cpu core on my machine fairly heavily, which is good.

```
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
for (doc, context) in nlp.pipe(lines, as_tuples=True, batch_size=1000):
    for ent in doc.ents:
        pass #handle each entity
```

I understand that I can use nlp.disable_pipes to disable certain elements. Is there anything I can disable that won't impact accuracy and that isn't required for NER?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For NER only with the transformer model `en_core_web_trf`, you can disable `["tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer"]`.

If you want to use a non-transformer model like `en_core_web_lg` (much faster but slightly lower accuracy), you can disable `["tok2vec", "tagger", "parser", "attribute_ruler", "lemmatizer"]` and use `nlp.pipe(n_process=-1)` for multiprocessing on all CPUs (or `n_process=N` to restrict to N CPUs).

Comment: Excellent, thanks. I will try the other model you suggested and compare to see what differences are found between entities.